# NodeJS: How to use for async helper method for async method

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm using `Async` library for asynchronous programming on NodeJS. I want to make a helper method (that also use async method), rather than put all code in same place.

Here is my sample code:

```
var solve = function() {
  async.waterfall([
      // a long working task. huh
      function (callback) {
          setTimeout(function() {
              console.log('hello world!');
              callback();
          }, 2000);
      },

      function (callback) {
          authorService.helperAsync();
      },

      function (callback) {
          setTimeout(function() {
              console.log('bye bye!');
          }, 2000);
      }

  ]);
};

solve();
```

In other file, I make an async function:

```
var helperAsync = function() {
    async.waterfall([
       function(callback) {
           console.log('task 1');
           callback();
       },
        function (callback) {
            console.log('task 2');
            callback();
        }
    ]);
}
```

I want the result should be:

```
Hello World
Task 1
Task 2
Bye Bye
```

But the output is only

```
Hello World
Task 1
Task 2
```

. How can I fix my code ?

Thanks :)

Comment: you never called `callback`. not even once. you're supposed to call it when the async action is complete, otherwise `async.waterfall` doesn't know that it is done and it can continue.

Comment: @KevinB Sorry because I'm just see this library. If I put all functions in one async, it will run true. So, how should I fix? thanks :)

Comment: by calling `callback` in the appropriate place, inside the settimeout. I thought i was pretty clear in my first comment.

Comment: @KevinB thanks. I have edited as you suggest. But the  last block (bye bye) not run. How can I notify ? I have edited my question. Please see again :)

Comment: You have to execute it in the other two functions too.

Comment: @KevinB thanks. I can fixed now. But why I always need to call `callback` at each function ? Some code I read online, they don't call callback. the return of previous function will be input of next function. thanks :)

Comment: It depends on the code being used. with the `async` module, you almost always have to execute a callback. Promises on the other hand can handle just returning a promise to the .then for example.

Comment: @KevinB http://postimg.org/image/3zo8yw6y5/ As this image I uploaded, you see that no callback is called. This code is used `async` also

Comment: bcrypt.hash executes it when it is done. so does dbc.query, and exports.user_by_uuid.

Comment: @KevinB ah. I understand. In those case, those function calls `callback` implicit by callback parameter, but in my case, no one called. So I must do it manually by call `callback`. right ?

Comment: Correct! something, somewhere, has to call the callback. Without that, the waterfall can't continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup each file to be used as a `module`, which involves `exporting` the function that you'd like to return, like so:

**solve.js**

```
var async = require('async');
var helperAsync = require('./helperAsync.js');

  module.exports = function solve() {

    async.waterfall([

        function helloOne(next) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('hello world!');
                return next();
            }, 2000);
        },

        function helperCall(next) {
            helperAsync(params, function(){
               return next();
            });
        },

        function byeBye(next) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('bye bye!');
                return next();
            }, 2000);
        }
    ], function(result){
      return result;
    });

  };
```

**helperAsync.js**

```
var async = require('async');

module.exports = function helperAsync (params, callback) {

  async.waterfall([
      function(next) {
         console.log('task 1');
         return next();
       },
        function (next) {
          console.log('task 2');
          return next();
        }
  ], function(result){
      return callback(result);
  });

};
```

I've renamed the `callback` from your `async.waterfall` to `next` in order to prevent confusion with the main callback of the module.

Comment: thanks :D Can I ask you, so in NodeJS, when we design a helper function, we should put a callback at the end of the parameter list for anyone who need it, right ?

Comment: Yes. All `modules` in nodejs require a callback to return the computed data.  You need to think of each `module` as an encapsulated little piece of software that exports a function that can be called from another function/module. Here's a good tutorial: http://howtonode.org/creating-custom-modules

Comment: My pleasure. Keep learning, you've got the spirit and the brains.

Comment: And you should also use async.series instead because async.waterfall doesn't guarantee order.